# while loop doesn't stop in js

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I want to use function with while to print only 10 numbers starting from the number I choose.

But while loop doesn't stop looping.

```js
id = prompt('Write any number.');
function numbering(a) {
    var i = a; 
    var j = a + 10;  
    while (i < j) {
       document.write(i);
       i++;
    }
};
numbering(id);
```

Comment: Replace [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) with [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Comment: Then input 0 value then you 0to9  as result

Comment: Just add: `a = +a;`. The unary operator (`+`) will cast the variable `a` to a number, since prompts actually returns `strings`, so using + on strings will result in **concatenating**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `function numbering(a) {`, the variable `a` is passed as string.

This results in `i` and `j` being set as string.

Taking example: 
Suppose you pass `2` as input, your variables will be set as `a="2"`, `i="2"` and `j="210"`. So according to your condition, it'll print starting from `2` till `209`.

You can change your code to parse `a` as number to achieve your result; something like:

```
function numbering(a) {
    a = parseInt(a);  //parse as Int here
    var i=a; var j=a+10;
    while (i < j) 
      {
         document.write(i);
         i++;
      }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var id = parseInt(prompt('Write any number.'), 10);
```

In your example id will be of type string and the comparisons won't work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a for-loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){ doSomething}
```

Comment: Sorry my question was wrong. Not from 0, but from the number I choose at prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this for-loop function :

```js
 id=prompt('Write any number.');
 function numbering(a) {
  for (let i = a; i < a + 10; i++){
    document.write(i);
  }
 };

numbering(id);
```

You can add a `parseInt(id)` to you numbering function parameter call if you want to parse the input into a number

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a number in the prompt, it is supplied as a string. Since you have not converted this into a number, the line `var j = a + 10` is actually joining the two values as if they were strings.

For example, if you enter "5" into the prompt, then `var j = "5" + 10` returns `"510"`. Only when you then compare the two variables in the while loop with `i < j` does it get interpreted as a number, and will loop from 5 to 510.

The easiest way to convert a string into a number is to use `parseInt(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt function returns a `string`.
The problem is that you are concatenating a `string` with the number 10.

If you write your variables to document, you can see the problem:

```
     id=prompt('Write any number.');
    function numbering(a) {
        var i=a; var j=a+10; 
        document.write(i);
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write(j);
        document.write("<br/>");
        //while (i < j){
        //  document.write(i);
        //  i++;
        //}
    };

         numbering(id);
```

This will fix your problem:

```
var id=parseInt(prompt('Write any number.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the parseInt function because what you getting from promt is string. For example 5 +10 . For javascript , it will be 510 .

```
     id=prompt('Write any number.');
function numbering(a) {
  var i=parseInt(a); var j=parseInt(a)+10; 
  while (i < j){
    document.write(i);i++;
  }};

             numbering(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write(i +"<br>");
```

In console i am getting proper result. just add line break to see whole result in  viewport